# Need a More Specific PHP While Loop for Querying MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I am querying a database and displaying data. I have a timestamp and a Facebook ID that I use to display the user's profile picture (using the Facebook graph). This is more of a PHP/Loop question than a FB Graph question though. Here's my bit of code that I'm working on:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fb_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo "<h1>".$lastone_month." ".$year_lastone."</h1>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$fb_id = $row['fb_id'];
$timestamp = date_parse($row['timestamp']);
$month = $timestamp['month'];
$year = $timestamp['year'];                                     
echo "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/".$fb_id."' target='_blank'><img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_id."/picture/' /></a>";
}
```

Eseentially what happens is I'm echoing the most recent month (this is in a bit of code before this). $lastone_month is a number (it's the number of the month of the most recent user that signed up). Let's say that it's January so the h1 would display 1/2013. I then have the while loop looping through the database and echoing out the user's profile picture in order of timestamp. What I would like it to do is to run the while loop until it reaches a row where $month is not equal to $lastone_month.

I can't use "&& $month==$lastone_month in the while loop because the $month value is not declared yet at that point. I tried an if statement around the echo line but that caused it to infinitely display one entry. I tried to declare row before the while loop and then declare $month and $year there too and then run the loop but that didn't work either. I'm thinking it's a really simple solution but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` to quit from loop at any point:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
  ...
  $month = $timestamp ['month'];
  if ($month != $lastone_month) break;
  ...
}
```

But more efficient is to use `WHERE` in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fb_id WHERE MONTH(timestamp)='$lastone_month' ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// build here timestamp which is your limit and name it $limit
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fb_id WHERE timestamp < "$limit" ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
```

Something like that